# UNC paths as current directories in batch file where admin rights are requested

Tags: batch-file, unc

I'm currently trying to write a batch files that automatically creates a folder structure including shortcuts.
For creating the shortcuts I use "mklink" which requires administrator privileges. 
I have used the code on this site
(http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-auto-elevate-a-batch-file-to-run-it-as-administrator/) for giving me these rights automatically.

However, the code down below works perfectly fine when I run it locally on my machine, but when I put it on a server location where it is intended to work the command prompt immediately closes after I have made my yes/no choice in the dialoge window for administrator rights.
I don't get an error code but I have figured out that it probably has to do with 
that "CMD DOES NOT SUPPORT UNC PATHS AS CURRENT DIRECTORIES".
I have tried using pushd and other things I found on forums to solve such problem but now I have started to run dry on ideas.

Does anyone have I clue how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

```
chcp 1252 

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Run as admin
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO =============================
ECHO The name of the main folder?    
ECHO =============================

:init
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
for %%k in (%0) do set batchName=%%~nk
set "vbsGetPrivileges=%temp%\OEgetPriv_%batchName%.vbs"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:checkPrivileges
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )

:getPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' (echo ELEV & shift /1 & goto gotPrivileges)
ECHO.
ECHO **************************************
ECHO Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation
ECHO **************************************

ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO args = "ELEV " >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO For Each strArg in WScript.Arguments >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO args = args ^& strArg ^& " "  >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO Next >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", args, "", "runas", 1 >>      "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
"%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%vbsGetPrivileges%" %*
exit /B

:gotPrivileges
setlocal & pushd .
cd /d %~dp0
if '%1'=='ELEV' (del "%vbsGetPrivileges%" 1>nul 2>nul  &  shift /1)

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

::Dialogwindow.
@echo off
title message

echo Skriv nedan^^!
set/p "Projektnamn=>"

:: Creates the folder structure
md "%~dp0"%Projektnamn%

md "%~dp0""%Projektnamn%"/"1. Projektpärm"
md "%~dp0""%Projektnamn%"/"1. Projektpärm"/"1. Tekniska specifikationer"
md "%~dp0""%Projektnamn%"/"1. Projektpärm"/"2. ÄTA,Beställning & Fakturering"
md "%~dp0""%Projektnamn%"/"1. Projektpärm"/"3. Tidplan"
md "%~dp0""%Projektnamn%"/"1. Projektpärm"/"4. Projektmöten"
md "%~dp0""%Projektnamn%"/"1. Projektpärm"/"5. Dagbok"
md "%~dp0""%Projektnamn%"/"1. Projektpärm"/"6. Kvalitet"
:: Genväg enlinjeschema, se kod för genväg

md "%~dp0""%Projektnamn%"/"2. Kretsschema"
md "%~dp0""%Projektnamn%"/"2. Kretsschema"/"1. Konstruktionsunderlag från    kund"

md "%~dp0""%Projektnamn%"/"3. Stationsdokumentation"
md "%~dp0""%Projektnamn%"/"3. Stationsdokumentation"/"1. Enlinjeschema"
md "%~dp0""%Projektnamn%"/"3. Stationsdokumentation"/"2. Blockschema"
md "%~dp0""%Projektnamn%"/"3. Stationsdokumentation"/"3. Förreglingsschema"
md "%~dp0""%Projektnamn%"/"3. Stationsdokumentation"/"4. Ritningsnummer"

md "%~dp0""%Projektnamn%"/"4. Skåpsdokumentation"
md "%~dp0""%Projektnamn%"/"4. Skåpsdokumentation"/"1. Skåpslayout"
md "%~dp0""%Projektnamn%"/"4. Skåpsdokumentation"/"2. Apparatlista"
md "%~dp0""%Projektnamn%"/"4. Skåpsdokumentation"/"3. Förbindningstabell"
md "%~dp0""%Projektnamn%"/"4. Skåpsdokumentation"/"4. Skyltlista & Etiketter"

:: Skapar RELATIVA Genvägarna
mklink /D "%~dp0%Projektnamn%\1. Projektpärm\7. Enlinjeschema" "..\3.     Stationsdokumentation\1. Enlinjeschema"
mklink /D "%~dp0%Projektnamn%\1. Projektpärm\8. Blockschema" "..\3.    Stationsdokumentation\2. Blockschema"
mklink /D "%~dp0%Projektnamn%\1. Projektpärm\9. Förreglingsschema" "..\3. Stationsdokumentation\3. Förreglingsschema"
mklink /D "%~dp0%Projektnamn%\1. Projektpärm\10. Skåpslayout" "..\4. Skåpsdokumentation\1. Skåpslayout"

pause
```

Comment: This is not what I call a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Anyway, you are probably looking for [`pushd`](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [`popd`](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)...

Comment: What happens if you open a cmd as administrator and run the batch from the share? By default locally mapped shares aren't available in UAC mode

Comment: @Mofi When the batch file is stored on my C: drive I run the batch file, this will take me to the dialoge window  where I get the administrator rights, after that I can write the name of my mainfolder and the batch file creates the folder structure including shortcuts.

When I on the other hand put the file on \\server\share\Batch.bat  and click on the batch file (this is how I intend to run it) the command prompt imitiately closes after the dialog window and it does not let my type the name of my mainfolder.
I want the batch file to be located only at the server. 
Is this not possible?

Comment: *UNC default paths are turned off by default as they used to crash older programs.[10]

The Dword registry value `DisableUNCCheck` at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`[10] allows the default directory to be UNC. `CD` command will refuse to change but placing a UNC path in Default Directory in a shortcut to `Cmd` or by using the `Start` command. `start "" /d \\127.0.0.1\C$ "cmd /k"` (`C$` share is for administrators).* From my one contribution at Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file#Setting_a_UNC_working_directory_from_a_shortcut

Answer (score 1):

Here is the batch code rewritten for this task and commented completely:

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Run as administrator
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
chcp 1252 >nul
cls

rem Define as target folder path the folder path of this batch file. This can
rem can be a folder on a local drive or on a network drive or even a UNC path.

rem It is also possible to use %CD% instead of %~dp0 to specify as target
rem folder path the current folder on starting this batch file which can
rem be different to batch file folder. But please note that Windows does
rem not support by default running a batch script from a network share
rem using UNC path. This is indicated by Windows with the message:

rem '\\ComputerName\ShareName\FolderName'
rem CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
rem UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.

rem So on using %CD% and running this batch file from a network share using
rem UNC path the target folder would be %SystemRoot% which is usually the
rem folder C:\Windows which is most likely not wanted as target folder path.

set "TargetFolder=%~dp0"
set "vbsGetPrivileges=%TEMP%\OEgetPriv_%~n0.vbs"

rem The console application NET with parameter FILE can be executed
rem successfully only if the account used for running this batch file
rem has local administrator privileges. See the Microsoft TechNet article
rem https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490702.aspx for details
rem about NET FILE.

rem The output written to handle STDOUT on successful execution is redirected
rem to device NUL to suppress it. The exit code of NET assigned to ERRORLEVEL
rem is in this case 0 indicating a successful execution.

rem But on a failed execution because of not having administrator
rem privileges NET outputs to handle STDERR the two error messages
rem "System error 5 has occurred." and "Access is denied." which
rem are redirected from handle STDERR to device NUL to suppress them.
rem And exit/return code of NET is 1 indicating a failed execution.

rem Read https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx
rem for details about using command redirection operators.

%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe FILE >nul 2>nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto RunMainCode

if "%~1"=="ELEV" (

    rem This condition is just for safety. If the batch file was started
    rem already a second time with ELEV as first parameter and execution
    rem of NET FILE failed nevertheless because of missing permissions,
    rem the batch file outputs an error message, waits for any key press
    rem by the user to make sure that the user had the chance to read the
    rem error message and then exits the batch file processing without
    rem doing anything at all.

    echo %~nx0 should run already with elevated privileges, but it isn't.
    echo/
    echo Press any key to exit %~nx0 without doing anything ...
    pause >nul
    goto :EOF
)

rem This batch file can be started without any parameter result in %* being
rem expanded to nothing which results in environment variable BatchArgs being
rem deleted if already existing or with project name as parameter which must
rem be enclosed in double quotes in case of containing 1 or more spaces.

rem As the batch file needs to be executed once again in a separate command
rem process running as local administrator for full access at least on local
rem machine it is necessary to prepare the parameters/arguments list. Each
rem double quote in the arguments list must be doubled to be correct escaped
rem in the VBScript file.

rem This is necessary as otherwise running this batch file with "My Project"
rem as first parameter would result in execution of the batch file by
rem the Windows Script Host as My Project without the double quotes as
rem arguments for the batch file and therefore the first parameter is on
rem elevated execution "My" instead of "My Project" as it was initially.

rem Many "run as administrator" solutions which can be found in world wide web
rem don't handle parameter strings correct which are enclosed in double quotes
rem because the parameter string has 1 or more spaces or other critical
rem characters requiring enclosing the parameter string in double quotes.

set "BatchArgs=%*"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if defined BatchArgs set "BatchArgs= !BatchArgs:"=""!"

rem Everything output by the ECHO command lines within the next command block
rem is redirected into the VBScript file created in the folder for temporary
rem files of current user with name of batch file in VBScript file name. This
rem makes it possible that multiple batch files with different names can run
rem at the same time using same code for creating a VBScript file to run the
rem batch file once again as administrator with elevated privileges.

rem For details on ShellExecute parameters see the Microsoft MSDN article
rem https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745.aspx

rem The tricky part is quoting the arguments list correct which should be
rem finally passed to cmd.exe executed from the VBScript. The command process
rem running the batch file with elevated privileges of local administrator
rem should automatically close after execution of batch file finished which
rem is the reason for first argument /C.

rem The second argument is the command to execute by `cmd.exe` which is
rem the batch file name with complete path which must be enclosed in double
rem quotes for safety in case of batch file name or path contains 1 or more
rem spaces. But additionally the batch file itself must be started with at
rem least 2 more arguments.

rem The first argument for the batch file is ELEV which is used as indication
rem to detected if this batch file is already started a second time with via
rem the VBScript using local built-in administrator account.

rem The second argument for the batch file is the target folder path which is
rem either the batch file folder or the current folder on starting this batch
rem file the first time depending or whatever is specified above as target
rem folder path.

rem And last all parameters passed to this batch file on initial run should
rem be also passed to second execution of this batch file under the different
rem environment of local built-in administrator account.

rem This nesting of batch file arguments in command processor arguments written
rem into a VBScript file which requires additionally escaping each double quote
rem within a string with one more double quote results in a strange syntax for
rem the line to write into the VBScript file.

(
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe", "/C """"%~f0"" ELEV ""!TargetFolder!""!BatchArgs!""", , "runas", 1
)>"%vbsGetPrivileges%"
endlocal

rem Now the created VBScript file can be executed with Windows Script Host.
rem Then the VBScript file can be deleted as not longer needed and processing
rem of this batch file under current user account ends resulting in returning
rem to command process which results in closing the console window if not
rem executed by cmd.exe started with option /K to keep the console window
rem open like on opening a command prompt window and running this batch
rem file from within the command prompt window.

%SystemRoot%\System32\wscript.exe "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
del "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
goto :EOF


rem Here starts the main code of the batch file which needs to be
rem executed with elevated privileges of a local administrator.

rem First is checked if the first parameter of the batch file is ELEV
rem which indicates that this batch file was started a second time
rem using local administrator account.

:RunMainCode
if "%~1"=="ELEV" (

    rem In this case the second argument is the target folder passed from
    rem initial run to this second run of the batch file. The current
    rem directory is now not anymore the initial current directory, but
    rem %SystemRoot%\System32 has set by Windows on starting a command
    rem process using RunAs and administrator account. This must be taken
    rem into account on further batch file processing.

    rem For this batch file it does not matter what is the current directory
    rem as it is written to work with the target folder defined on starting
    rem the batch file (initially). So there is no need to use  CD /D "%~dp0"
    rem or  PUSHD "%~dp0"  as many "run as administrator" solutions use to
    rem change the current directory to directory of the batch file. There
    rem is also no need for  CD /D "%~2"  or  PUSHD "%~2"  here.

    rem The two additionally added arguments ELEV and the target folder
    rem path are removed from the arguments lists by using twice the
    rem command SHIFT to restore the initial arguments list.

    set "TargetFolder=%~2"
    shift /1
    shift /1
)

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Now it is checked if the last character of the target folder path is
rem a backslash character which is not the case when using %CD% and the
rem current directory on starting the batch file is not the root directory
rem of a drive. In this case append a backslash to target folder path.

if not "%TargetFolder:~-1%" == "\" set "TargetFolder=%TargetFolder%\"

rem If this batch file was started (initially) without any parameter string,
rem prompt the batch file user for the project folder name and use the input
rem string without checking if being valid as folder name. Otherwise interpret
rem the first parameter string as project folder name.

if "%~1" == "" (
    echo/
    echo ============================
    echo The name of the main folder?
    echo ============================
    echo/
    set "Projektnamn=:invalid:"
    set /P "Projektnamn=>"
    echo/
) else (
    set "Projektnamn=%~1"
)

rem Create the main project folder and check if this was successful. On an
rem error like such a folder exists already, or the user has no permissions
rem to create this folder, or the folder name contains characters being not
rem valid for a folder name like the default string :invalid: used in case
rem of user just hits RETURN or ENTER instead of entering a folder name,
rem the command MD outputs an appropriate error message. The batch file
rem halts in this case the batch file execution until the user hits any
rem key before exiting without doing anything at all.

md "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!"
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo/
    echo Press any key to exit %~nx0 without doing anything ...
    pause >nul
    endlocal
    goto :EOF
)

rem Create the folder structure and the symbolic directory links.
rem The command MD with command extensions enabled as done at top of this
rem batch file creates automatically the entire directory tree if necessary.

md "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!\1. Projektpärm\1. Tekniska specifikationer"
md "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!\1. Projektpärm\2. ÄTA,Beställning & Fakturering"
md "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!\1. Projektpärm\3. Tidplan"
md "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!\1. Projektpärm\4. Projektmöten"
md "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!\1. Projektpärm\5. Dagbok"
md "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!\1. Projektpärm\6. Kvalitet"

:: Genväg enlinjeschema, se kod för genväg
md "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!\2. Kretsschema\1. Konstruktionsunderlag från kund"

md "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!\3. Stationsdokumentation\1. Enlinjeschema"
md "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!\3. Stationsdokumentation\2. Blockschema"
md "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!\3. Stationsdokumentation\3. Förreglingsschema"
md "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!\3. Stationsdokumentation\4. Ritningsnummer"

md "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!\4. Skåpsdokumentation\1. Skåpslayout"
md "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!\4. Skåpsdokumentation\2. Apparatlista"
md "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!\4. Skåpsdokumentation\3. Förbindningstabell"
md "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!\4. Skåpsdokumentation\4. Skyltlista & Etiketter"

:: Skapar RELATIVA Genvägarna
mklink /D "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!\1. Projektpärm\7. Enlinjeschema" "..\3. Stationsdokumentation\1. Enlinjeschema" >nul
mklink /D "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!\1. Projektpärm\8. Blockschema" "..\3. Stationsdokumentation\2. Blockschema" >nul
mklink /D "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!\1. Projektpärm\9. Förreglingsschema" "..\3. Stationsdokumentation\3. Förreglingsschema" >nul
mklink /D "%TargetFolder%!Projektnamn!\1. Projektpärm\10. Skåpslayout" "..\4. Skåpsdokumentation\1. Skåpslayout" >nul
endlocal
endlocal
```

This batch file works with whatever is the current directory on starting the batch file with current user account or with built-in local administrator account as everything is written to work independent on what is the current directory.

The current directory is `%SystemRoot%` in case of the batch file is stored in a folder on a network share opened using UNC path and executed by double clicking on it.

The current directory is `%SystemRoot%\System32` on running it a second time with elevated privileges if the current user has no administrator privileges.

However, if the local administrator account has no read & execute permissions on the network share, `cmd.exe` can't execute the batch file with using UNC path directly from network share.

In the long line written as second line into the VBScript file replace `/C` by `/K` to keep open the console window opened on second execution of the batch file after elevation to administrator level to be able to read the error messages output by Windows command interpreter.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `chcp /?`
- `cls /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `mklink /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `shift /?`
- `wscript /?` (or `cscript /?` as `cscript.exe` could be also used.)

Microsoft articles referenced in the comments of the batch code:

- [Net file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490702.aspx)
- [Shell.ShellExecute method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745.aspx)
- [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx)

**Note:** All lines starting with `rem` after 0 or more leading spaces can be safely removed like all lines starting with `::` (invalid label used for comment lines).

Comment: Now I get the dialoge window but the original problem remains, when I run it on the network drive the command prompt immediately shuts down after I have made the "yes" choice for administrator rights. Locally it works fine!
If I run it through CMD it says : Ny_mappstruktur.bat is not an internal commando, nor external, software or command file.

This was the problem from the beginning.

Comment: @user7305472 The built-in local administrator account used after elevating the batch file to administrator level usually does not have any access permissions on a public share on a server in a network. The network administrator accounts in a domain have usually full access on shares on a server in the domain, but not the Windows built-in  local administrator account. My test worked as the share was on my own computer and therefore the local administrator account has full access to this share, too.

Comment: Thank you!
So what you are saying is that I will not be able to create the folder structure on the server since I'm not a network administator?

I will add the additional information!

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: The batch file as is works definitely also with batch file stored on shared folder and started using UNC path. But it depends on the access permissions of the share if it is possible that the batch file has access to share after elevation to administrator and create the folder structure as well as the symbolic links. See also [Permission to make symbolic links in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/104845/) and [How do I create a link in Windows 7 home premium as a regular user?](http://superuser.com/questions/124679/)